# Table of relative values from relative table

Tags: sql

I'm having a hard time taking this decision. I have a schema where I want a product from a specific category to have specific values from that category.

I've made my way in to 5 tables and I just want to know if this is the right way of doing it.

Scenario:
Main tables:

```
Element (id, name, category_ID)
Category (id, name)
Characteristic (id, name, unity)
```

I want a Category to have specific number of Characteristics (ie. a computer needs to have the characteristics of cpu, ram, screensize, etc. and a mouse needs to have isCordless, numberOfButtons, etc.), so I've created the table Category_has_Characteristic:

```
Category_has_Characteristic(id_category, id_characteristic)
```

For setting the specific element value to each characteristic from the category I've created this table:

```
Element_has_Characteristic ( id_element, id_Category_has_Characteristic, value)
```

is this the best approach to create a table to have the specific element values for each characteristic ?

Am I missing something or this is the only/best way of doing it?

any comment will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classic case of overnormalization.  Consider a table:

```
Category
  id
  name varchar(50)
  isCordless bit
  numberOfButtons int
  ...
```

This leads to way simpler queries.  You only need a many-to-many relation if your characteristics are dynamic.  For example, if you're planning to write a control panel that your users can use to add characteristics to a category.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concept quite well, but in that case the Category table have some fixed rows for some characteristic (isCordless, numberOfButtons), and i don't want that to happen. Why? Because the element table will have totally different products, and because of that, different characteristics of course.

Comment: Ok, I've understand what you are saying with the "overnormalization" now. So in this case you think it's better to create a new table for each category of elements? even if the user can add new categories, and subsequently new characteristics for that category ?

Comment: @NewK: Well I'd either create 1 table called Category with as many columns as you like.  Only if that didn't work out would I add additional tables. At the end of the day, you should only spend complexity where it adds value.  Good luck!